# Use session_set_cookie_params or session_start options

Tags: php, session-variables

Where should session cookies options go? in `session_start` or `session_set_cookie_params`?

The documentation at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start) is a bit unclear one these as they don't mention `session_set_cookie_params`. Are the cookie paramenters in php.int and `session_set_ cookie_params` overwritten by the ones in `sessions_start`? Can I combine all settings (cookie and otherwise) in one call to `session_start`?

EDIT: What is the point of `session_set_cookie_params` if these can be nuked by whatever is specified in `session_start`?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php: _"options: 
If provided, this is an associative array of options that **will override the currently set session configuration directives**."_ - what is unclear about that?

Comment: As the authors of php.net are not explicit on that at leatst not in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) I can guess but not be sure by you assesment. I will add a note on php.net if you are sure.

Comment: _"What is the point of session_set_cookie_params if these can be nuked by whatever is specified in session_start?"_ - `session_set_cookie_params` is simply "older", existed already before `session_start` would take any "options", that was only added in later PHP versions.

Comment: I don't know if the German translation is up to date (translations often get outdated) but there're many ways to change configurations, what means there're a lot of combinations. It isn't practical to document them all explicitly.

Comment: Regarding your follow-up question, backward compatibility aside, think of them as default values rather than rules to enforce.

Comment: @CBroe that seems to be the most likely situation. Weren't options introduced in PHP 7? `session_set_cookie_params` is PHP4. So that was indeed long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The function `session_set_cookie_params` can be considered obsolete as all settings can now (since PHP7) be set as part of the options array to `session_start`.
(Source [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#128883))

To avoid clutter include the cookie settings in this options parameter.

An argument to still use the `session_set_cookie_params` function is to distinguish between session settings and cookie settings related to sessions.